# Special label for a item

Tags: enumerate

I am using

```
\begin{enumerate}[start=1,label={{\bf{Claim \arabic*.}}}]
\item
....
\item
\begin{enumerate}
```

and it works fine. I get my output as

[image: output]

Now, now and then I would like to have a different item label, something like:

[image: wished output]

Is there a quick trick? I am not able to see it. I am using `\usepackage{enumitem}`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be misusing (abusing?) the powers of the `enumitem` package. I think you'd be better off loading the `amsmthm` package and defining a numbered environment called `claim` and an unnumbered environment named `comment`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition} % use upright lettering
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
\newtheorem*{comment}{Comment}

\begin{document}

\begin{claim} 
bla bla bla 
\end{claim}
\begin{comment} 
ble ble ble 
\end{comment}
\begin{claim} 
bli bli bli 
\end{claim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll check if it suits my needs.

Comment: Yes, your are right, I was abusing the powers of the enumitem package.